# How to restrict the date picker with min and max values on I phone using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iphone

I am using a JavaScript function for min and max values for input type date. It is working fine on Android mobile, but in I phone Am unable to restrict the calendar with max and min values.

Here is my code:

JS:

```
 var today = new Date();
var maxAge = 18;
var minAge = 130;
vm.maxAge = new Date(today.getFullYear() - maxAge, today.getMonth(), today.getDate());
vm.minAge = new Date(today.getFullYear() - minAge, today.getMonth(), today.getDate());
```

HTML:

```
     <input id="date" type="date"  name="dateOfBirth" ng-model="dateOfBirth" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" ng-required="true" min="{{minAge | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" max="{{maxAge | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed a curly brace can check it once

```
 <input id="date" type="date"  name="dateOfBirth" ng-model="dateOfBirth" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" ng-required="true" min="{{minAge | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" max="{{maxAge | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" /
```